# Getting a value from 3rd party website API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

So I'm desperately trying to pull a value from a 3rd party website API. The information is formatted in the following way:

[Website's API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JchTj.png)

I'd like to pull out a value for "price". So far I've tried many different codes but all have failed. I've also spent a lot of time searching for a solution but without succes. At the moment my code for obtaining the value looks like this, but it's obviously not complete and incorrect as I'm new to NodeJs:

```
var Request = require("request");
Request.get("url", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

And yes the url is actually inserted in my code + I know that this should only display the full JSON structure, but it fails to do even that :/

Any kind of advice would be welcome :)

EDIT: So I've fixed that issue with not getting data :) However I still need to filter my data in order to pull out the "price" value. As of now my data displays this: "data: { items_on_sale: [ [Object] ], items_not_on_sale: [] } }"

Comment: Is this showing any error in console?

Comment: Just gives the "status: 'fail' "

Comment: have you tried with `https`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with 2FA code. It wasn't generating properly. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**status: 'fail'** : The api is not replying with the data.Does the url require any query params/body to be passed with the url?

Try hitting the api using postman/SoapUI and check the response there.

also try printing the **response** in the log,what values do you get?

```
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
```

Comment: It responds with: "statusCode: 401".
Yes it does need querry parameters. The website's support said it has something to do with my code not generating the TOTP code properly.

Comment: **So I've fixed that issue with not getting data :)**
However I still need to filter my data in order to pull out the "price" value. As of now my data displays this: "data: { items_on_sale: [ [Object] ], items_not_on_sale: [] } }"

Comment: Are you still not able to pull out the data (price in your case) ? 
To view the full JSON of the response , write the following code
console.log(JSON.stringify(body,null,4));